# Generator of a generated $C_0$ semigroup

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroups-of-operators

Consider a $C_0$-semigroup $S_t:\mathscr{B(H)} \to \mathscr{B(H)}$ with generator $U$. Now define  $P_t:\mathscr{B_1(H)} \to \mathscr{B_1(H)}$ where $P_t(\rho)=S_t\rho S_t^*$. How can I prove  $P_t$ to be $C_0$-semigroup and the generator of $P_t$ is given by $A$, where $A(\rho)=U\rho+\rho U^*$?

Comment: This doesn't look like a research question.  Bratteli and Robinson is my favorite source for the basic theory of semigroups of operators.

Comment: What is ${\mathcal B}_1({\mathcal H})$?

Comment: If U is bounded, this is rather obvious. However, if U is unbounded, there is in general an issue of domains. It is easy to come up with example where $U\rho$ is an unbounded operator, but $A(\rho)$ is bounded. Hence the generator of $P_t$ will in general be an extension of $A$.

Answer (score 5):

The semigroups you construct is in general only weak-* continuous. Are you looking for so-called implemented semigroups?

See for example

*Alber, Jochen*, [**On implemented semigroups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s002330010082), Semigroup Forum 63, No. 3, 371-386 (2001). [ZBL1041.47028](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1041.47028).

Comment: Andras, I do not understand. Would this semigroup be in general only weak*-continuous even if $\mathcal H$ is a Hilbert space? I thought this may happen only if the semigroup acts on a non-reflexive Banach space.

Comment: $\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ is in general a non-reflexive Banach space...

Comment: oh. such a stupid mistake. of course, you are right.